# .htaccess mod_rewrite language in URL + parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to write a rule, that would redirect URL like this:

```
myweb.com/en/page
```

to

```
myweb.com/page.php?lang=en
```

And URL like this

```
myweb.com/en/page?do=action
```

to

```
myweb.com/page.php?lang=en&do=action
```

This code:

```
RewriteRule ^/(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

ignores another parameters (do in example above).

What should I change? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the QSA (Query String Append) flag in you rule :

```
RewriteRule ^/(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```